# Combining 2 functions

Tags: jquery

Hey All,
Thanks in advance for helping me solve this. Any advice you have is greatly appreciated. I'll jump right into it.

### Function 1

This function adds a set of checkboxes to page from an external file. This function can take place multiple times so that a user can create multiple forms to submit simultaniously

```
$( '#partners_internal_item_additem' ).click( function( e ){
        $( '#partners_program_registration' ).append(
            $( '<div>' ).load( 'accomodationpartners/programregistration1.html' )
        );
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

This is what it returns:

```
<div class="partners_internal_item">
<div class="partners_internal_item_subhdrfull"><h2>Select a Product to Register For:</h2></div>
<div class="partners_internal_product_select">
    <fieldset><input type="checkbox" class="productselect" id="productselect_daytrip" /><label for="productselect_daytrip">Day Trip</label></fieldset>
    <fieldset><input type="checkbox" class="productselect" id="productselect_courseregistraion" /><label for="productselect_courseregistraion">Course Registration</label></fieldset>
    <fieldset><input type="checkbox" class="productselect" id="productselect_socialbusinessgroup" /><label for="productselect_socialbusinessgroup">Social/Business Group</label></fieldset>
    <fieldset><input type="checkbox" class="productselect" id="productselect_paddlefest" /><label for="productselect_paddlefest">Paddlefest</label></fieldset>
    <fieldset><input type="checkbox" class="productselect" id="productselect_paddleplay" /><label for="productselect_paddleplay">Paddle and Play</label></fieldset>
</div>
<div class="partners_internal_product_registration">hi</div>
```

### Function 2

This function selects a checkbox and unselects all of the others. Then this function builds a URL to load into a div based on the checkbox selected.

```
var checkboxes = $(':checkbox.productselect');
checkboxes.click(function() {
    /* uncheck checkboxes that aren't this one */
    $(checkboxes).not($(this)).attr('checked', false);
    /* get the name of the page to load
    from the id of the checkbox selected */
    var checkboxID = $(this).attr('id');
    var checkboxIDArray = checkboxID.split('_');
    var loadString = 'accomodationpartners/'+checkboxIDArray[1]+'.php';
    /* load the html into the div */
    $('.partners_internal_product_registration').load(loadString);
});
```

### Function 3

This function was recently added to help contain the result of the previous function.The reason being is that Function #1 can happen multiple times leaves copies of the same HTML with the same classes. Then when the user completes function #2 it effects all of the other one I cannot seem to integrate  function #3 seamlessly into the equation.

```
 $('.partners_internal_product_select input[type=checkbox]').live('change', function(){
   // figure out which checkbox was checked and whatever
   // but only affect the registration that holds the checkbox:
   var AffectedRegistration = $(this).closest('.partners_internal_product_select');
   // this is where I try to incorporate function #2
});
```

Comment: The goal of function 3 isn't clear. What do you mean by "contain the result of the previous function?" The title of your question says "combining two functions," but I don't see how function 3 is an attempt to combine functions 1 and 2. Would you mind clarifying your question?

Comment: Matt:
I ran into a problem because there were multiple sets of checkboxes with the same classes on the page. I attempted to try to use .closest to isolate the .load(of ftn #2) to the set of checkboxes that are being used. When function #2 fires and there are multiple checkboxes, it affects them all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand your ajax call into the long form in order wrap up your additional function  in a callback. The callback fires **after** the ajax content is loaded. This is key.

```
$( '#partners_internal_item_additem' ).click( function( e ){
  $.ajax({
    url: "accomodationpartners/programregistration1.html",
    success: function(){
      function2();
      function3();
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's the perfect time to read about jquery's new deferred feature:
http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/